# how to analyze the code by sonarqube after the user's commitment and before pushing to the remote git repository?

Tags: git, sonarqube, devops

We have an issue for designing a scenario with remote git server and sonarqube.
In other words, we established ***a remote git server and a community sonarqube sever*** separately;

& want that on each push action in every branches and before final pushing to the remote git repository, the user committed code to be analyzed by sonarqube.

Now, if the scan result and quality gates be passed then it pushed to the remote git repo. Otherwise, give the appropriate message to the user and push action be canceled.

We just found out that to use the "**pre-receive hook**" or "**update hook**" in the remote git repository to send the information to Sonarqube before it pushed. but how?

In addition, we can not use the bitbucket tool or etc.

What do you think is the best solution, friends? and how to do it?
Thank you very much for any help.
Best regards...

Comment: Sounds to me like a job for continuous integration server like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a build server like Jenkins, you're going to have to do all of this manually.  What you'll need to do is create a feature branch with your proposed changes, and run a sonarqube scan on the feature branch.  When you're satisfied with the results, then you can merge the feature branch to your target branch.

Comment: Hello Mr. Engineer @David M. Karr ;
Thank you very much for your answers and tips.
We also have Jenkins, Docker and Ansible.
Now how do you propose to implement it?
 best regards